# Curl IMAP Gmail

Tags: curl, gmail, imap, libcurl, gmail-imap

I'm trying to use Curl (actually libcurl) to list the emails in the Sent Mail directory of my gmail account.

The inbox directory works fine, however directories under [Gmail] don't, because square brackets aren't allowed in URLS. I've tried the -g flag, without any success.

```
.\curl.exe "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993/[Gmail]/Sent Mail" --cacert ".\cacert.pem" -u user:pass
```

Yields:

> curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

```
.\curl.exe "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993/[Gmail]/Sent Mail" --cacert ".\cacert.pem" -u user:pass -g
```

Yields:

> curl: (3) [globbing] error: bad range specification after pos 29

Can anyone see how I'm going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried percent encoding the [  and ]?

Comment: Yes... ".\curl.exe "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993/%5BGmail%5D/Sent Mail" --cacert ".\cacert.pem" -u user:password" results in "curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL".

Comment: It seems that this is actually the most success I've had...looking at the output from the verbose flag. Curl's at least trying to select the folder `> A003 LIST ""[Gmail]/Sent Mail"" *
< A003 BAD Could not parse command`. It looks like this might be failing due to the additional quotes (In this case, the error is `curl: (21) Quote command returned error`).

Comment: Looks potentially like a bug in curl, that is indeed an invalid list command, there should be a space between the empty quote pair and the folder name.

Comment: I've managed to get it to work correctly now (and additionally percent encoding the space), by providing the -X flag for a custom IMAP request (to search for the email I'm looking for).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I provided this as a comment to my question, but I've managed to get it to work correctly now, and additionally percent encoding the space, by providing the -X flag for a custom IMAP request, to search for the email I was looking for.

Comment: There was an additional issue with this, my custom IMAP request wasn't supported in CURL, so I had to add it myself to the codebase.

Answer (score 3):

[Switch off globbing](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-g) if you want to use [] in the URL.

Comment: I'm getting `curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL` when I use -g. But it works fine when I don't specify the folder (just "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993/"). So I presume this has to be something to do with the folder selection (`/[Gmail]/Sent Mail`) part of the URL. I've tried `/\[Gmail\]/Sent Mail`, `/[Gmail]/Sent%20Mail`, `/\[Gmail]\/Sent%20Mail`, `/[Gmail]/Sent`, `/\[Gmail\]/Sent`, `/Sent` all with the -g flag and I get the same illegal URL message.

Comment: In cURL 7.52.1, `/%5BGmail%5DSent%20Mail` is work @Alex